# Converting a string that represents a list, into an actual list object

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have a string that represents a list:

```
"[22, 33, 36, 41, 46, 49, 56, 72, 85, 92, 95, 98, 107, 118, 120, 123, 124, 126, 127, 130, 149, 157, 161, 171, 174, 177, 187, 195, 225, 302, 316, 359, 360, 363, 396, 479, 486, 491]"
```

I would like to turn that litteral string into an actual list. I suppose to could regex out the numbers and loop over then (`append()`) but is there an easier way? Not sure how I would set that up as a regex.

Comment: Looking like there are a *lot* of ways to do this. This page in it's entirety should have an 'accept answer' check mark. Keep them coming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
>>> import ast
>>> i = ast.literal_eval('[22, 33, 36, 41, 46, 49, 56]')
>>> i[3]
41
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

```
import json
x=json.loads("[22, 33, 36, 41, 46, 49, 56, 72, 85, 92, 95, 98, 107, 118, 120, 123, 124, 126, 127, 130, 149, 157, 161, 171, 174, 177, 187, 195, 225, 302, 316, 359, 360, 363, 396, 479, 486, 491]")
```

Answer (score 2):

If your actual string is

```
s = "[22, 33, 36, 41, 46, 49, 56, 72, 85, 92, 95, 98, 107, 118, 120, 123, 124, 126, 127, 130, 149, 157, 161, 171, 174, 177, 187, 195, 225, 302, 316, 359, 360, 363, 396, 479, 486, 491]"
```

then this will do the trick:

```
[int(n) for n in s[1:-1].split(', ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sl = "[22, 33, 36, 41, 46, 49, 56, 72, 85, 92, 95, 98, 107, 118, 120, 123, 124, 126, 127, 130, 149, 157, 161, 171, 174, 177, 187, 195, 225, 302, 316, 359, 360, 363, 396, 479, 486, 491]"
sl = sl.lstrip('[')
sl = sl.rstrip(']')
sl = sl.split(',')
```

Ugly and hacky, but it'll work!

Comment: ugly, hacky, and delivers a list of `str` objects -- should be `int` objects

Comment: In my case I have `;`-separated values in the string, so it looks like this is only way I can do it. I mean, with `split`. `ast.literal_eval` doesn't support any manipulation of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `eval` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval

```
>>> lst = eval("[22, 33, 36, 41, 46, 49, 56, 72, 85, 92, 95, 98, 107, 118, 120, 123, 124, 126, 127, 130, 149, 157, 161, 171, 174, 177, 187, 195, 225, 302, 316, 359, 360, 363, 396, 479, 486, 491]")
>>> type(lst)
<type 'list'>
>>> lst[0]
22
```