# Converting String to List

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string that represents a list, into an actual list object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214344/converting-a-string-that-represents-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object)

hi,

i have a string in this format:

```
>>> x="(174,185)"
>>> x
'(174,185)'
```

how can i convert this string to list so that i can access the index 0 as 174 and index 1 as 185? i'm using Python 2.5 & Win XP.
i tried a few ways but it doesn't work well. appreciate your advice. tq

```
>>> y=x.split(",")
>>> y
['(174', '185)']
>>> y[0]
'(174'
>>> [int(x) for x in x.split(",")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    [int(x) for x in x.split(",")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(174'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this

```
y=x[1:-1].split(",")
```

that strips off the parens before splitting

```
>>> x="(174,185)"
>>> map(int, x[1:-1].split(','))
[174, 185]
```

You could also use literal_eval if you have python2.6+

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(x)
(174, 185)
>>>
```

Comment: tq, this works great! once get to list, can access the index.

Comment: btw, what does x[1:-1] mean? tq

Comment: yes i get what you mean, you are only taking the int values in the parens and split it by a comma. great. :)