# list.__str__ reversed

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string that represents a list, into an actual list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214344/converting-a-string-that-represents-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object)

Having a string like this:

```
"[81, 102, 114, 132, 194, 210, 228, 317, 357, 358, 379, 396, 407, 417, 418, 420, 470, 471, 506, 526, 533, 538]"
```

How can I parse it easily into the corresponding list?

I know I could use the `re` module or splitting by `", "`, etc.

Is there any already existing function to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[81, 102, 114, 132, 194, 210, 228, 317, 357, 358, 379, 396, 407, 417, 418, 420, 470, 471, 506, 526, 533, 538]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[81, 102, 114, 132, 194, 210, 228, 317, 357, 358, 379, 396, 407, 417, 418, 420, 470, 471, 506, 526, 533, 538]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = "[81, 102, 114, 132]"
>>> map(int, l.strip("[]").split(", "))
[81, 102, 114, 132]
```

For Python 3+ you need to make list from `map` iterator:

```
>>> l = "[81, 102, 114, 132]"
>>> list(map(int, l.strip("[]").split(", ")))
[81, 102, 114, 132]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way is to use [eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). That's often considered bad practice, though, because it can lead to security problems.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is equally direct, and has no security issues.