# Python string to list conversion

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

i  have a `string` like this

```
sample="[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50]"
```

how do i convert that to `list`? I am expecting the output to be list, like this

```
output=[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50]
```

I am aware of `split()` function but in this case if i use

```
sample.split(',')
```

it will take in the `[` and `]` symbols. Is there any easy way to do it?

**EDIT** Sorry for the duplicate post..I didn't see this post until now
[Converting a string that represents a list, into an actual list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214344/converting-a-string-that-represents-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object?rq=1)

Comment: `output=json.loads(sample)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use standard string methods with python:

```
output = sample.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split(', ')
```

if you use `.split(',')` instead of `.split(',')` you will get the spaces along with the values!

you can convert all values to int using:

```
output = map(lambda x: int(x), output)
```

or load your string as json:

```
import json
output = json.loads(sample)
```

as a happy coincidence, json lists have the same notation as python lists! :-)

Comment: thanks a lot!I didn't know about `lstrip` and `rstrip` until now.. very useful stuff.

Comment: @ChrisAung Actually calling `sample.strip('[]')` is equivalent to `sample.lstrip('[').rstrip(']')`. Most of the method that have `r` and `l` versions also have a version without prefix that works on both ends of the string.

Comment: @Bakuriu you're right about that, but I prefer making it explicit when I can, so that a string that is not a good formatted list will just break. Explicit is better than implicit ;-).

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to be dealing with Python-esque types (such as tuples for instance), you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

sample="[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50]"

sample_list = literal_eval(sample)
print type(sample_list), type(sample_list[0]), sample_list
# <type 'list'> <type 'int'> [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50]
```

Comment: good one, Jon, I did not know about `ast.literal_eval`