# Converting a string of the form '[a, b, c]' to a list in python without going through list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, type-conversion

Python beginner question:

Is there a way to convert a string of the form `'[a, b, c]'` directly into a list?

As in `type(f('[a, b, c]')) is list == True`/`isinstance(f('[a, b, c]'), list) is True` for some method or function `f`? Please note, the final lists should have the elements as individual strings, i.e. `f('[a, b, c]') returns ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214344/converting-a-string-that-represents-a-list-into-an-actual-list-object?rq=1). `ast.literal_eval()` Fails with error:

```
ValueError: malformed string
```

My input list (string) isn't unicode marked, and the items are not individually `string` or `int`.

Is there a builtin for this kind of conversion? This is essentially a 'form' question. I am trying to understand if there is a `pythonic` way of doing this without writing a longish function using splitting the string and conversion.

Insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, there isn't a built-in for this - why doesn't your string have quotes around the list contents? Where do you get it from?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a list comprehension?

Comment: How should it deal with `"[a, 1, b]"` - should it give `["a", "1", "b"]` or `["a", 1, "b"]`?  Either way it is going to need a list comprehension or loop to parse the string because it is not a valid string representation of a list.

Comment: also, how should it deal with nested lists?

Comment: is your list will be always in this format ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I get it from a string of the shape [a, b, c]@abc.com.

Comment: @timegb: as I explained, it is a matter of form, I am trying to learn how to write it more pythonically, as in brevity and elegance. list comprehension is extrmely pythonic, I agree though.

Comment: @CoriolisForce, what happens for ints and  sublists etc..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the source of this emits the strings in that particular format. Once I have the list, it will be further processed to extract strings in a a@abc.com, b@abc.com etc. we don't know how many strings there will be.

Comment: @CoriolisForce, my question is what happens with something like '[a, b, c,1, 2, 3,[3,4]]'?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, in that case, this solution breaks, but honestly I didn't ask that in the question. Any insight would be most interesting though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all, I think this is a great discussion. I also think that the idea also is to make the code more generic than hard coded. Any insights will be well-appreciated. Taking from @PadraicCunningham's point, I think it'd be nice if we can generalize this code a bit, so that it can, if needed be, applied to nested phenomena. Thanks again.
Also, I think any insights on this part of the question would be helpful:
"I am trying to understand if there is a pythonic way of doing this without writing a longish function using splitting the string and conversion."

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = '[a ,b, c]'
s = s.replace(" ", "")
l = s[1:-1].split(',')
```

Comment: Gives `['a ', 'b', ' c']`, not `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Easily fixable with a list comprehension of course.

Comment: you will need to use literal_eval if there are any data structures in your list or sublists etc.. will be strings

Comment: @PadraicCunningham as far as the specs of the op go every element of the list is supposed to be a string

Comment: This breaks on nested lists - '[a, b, [c, d]]' would become ['a', 'b', ' [c', ' d]']

Comment: @timgeb, the sublist would not become a string

Comment: I don't think the OP considered nested lists. I asked him in the comments to the question, but he did not respond...

Comment: I don't think the OP did either but without using liter_eval I cannot see how anything other than simple cases like in the example will be solved.

Comment: @timegb: sorry, I was on another tab. List comps aren't needed.

Comment: This works, but is it possible to do away with the `s[1:-1]`? I think that makes it looks a little hard-coded.

Comment: @CoriolisForce it's a pythonic way to remove the first and the last char in string and it's doesn't look more "hard-coded" than an other way.

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP explicitly asks for a non list comprehension solution, however just for those who might be interested in a solution involving list comprehension I leave this code:

```
>>> s = "[a, 1, b]"
>>> s = [int(i) if i.strip().isdigit() else i.strip() for i in s[1:-1].split(",")]
>>> print(s)
 ['a', 1, 'b']
```

It also takes into accounts the type of the elements, ints are converted to `int`.

Comment: The question title states "without going through list comprehension", if someone comes looking here for a solution using list comp I think they  have some bigger problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `literal_eval` this keeps ints as ints and preserves sublists.

```
In [7]: import re

In [8]: d='[a, b, c, 4, 5, 6,[1,4]]'

In [9]: from ast import literal_eval

In [10]: lit = literal_eval(re.sub('([A-Za-z])', r'"\1"', d))

In [11]: lit[6]
Out[11]: [1, 4]

In [12]: type(lit[6])
Out[12]: list

In [13]: lit
Out[13]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, [1, 4]]
```

If you want to mix numbers and letters you  would need to convert all the ints to strings also.

You can also add to the pattern to find strings including `@` and `.`:

```
In [16]: d='[a, ba, c, 4, 5, 6,[1,4],me@you.com]'

In [17]: lit = literal_eval(re.sub('([A-Za-z@.])', r'"\1"', d))

In [18]: lit
Out[18]: ['a', 'ba', 'c', 4, 5, 6, [1, 4], 'me@you.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
s = '[a, b, c]'
s = s[1:-1]
s = s.split(', ')
```

or as a one-liner:

```
s = s[1:-1].split(', ')
```

Comment: If possible, can that `s[1:-1]` be replaced by something else? As I wrote above, makes it look a little hard-coded.

Comment: The only other alternative I know of would be `s = s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')`, but I think `s[1:-1]` is better because it says 's excluding the first and last character of s', which is exactly what we want. It's standard Python AFAIK.

Comment: this will give s=["'a'","'b'","'c'"]

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is way for transforming string "[a,b,c]" directly into a list:

```
a="hello"
b=" "
c="world"

lststr = "[a,b,c]"

# now 'exec()' can be used for declaring a variable 
# and assigning string 'lststr' to it as a list variable

exec("lstvar = "+lststr)
```